# Make multiboot ISO with EFI support in windows

Tags: linux, windows, windows-8, iso-image, uefi

I currently have 3 ISOs.

- Windows 8.1 64-bit EFI ISO
- Debian 8 Network Install 64-bit
- Ubuntu 15.05 64-bit

I would like to make it into a mutiple-distro linux install ISO. It needs to support EFI, and show the user a menu to choose the ISO to boot from. The tool needs to work on Windows. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE 26/8/15 - 13:50**

Have a look at this website: [XBoot](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/insert-multiple-iso-images-into-single-multiboot-usb-iso-file-with-xboot/). 
Looking at it, this will allow you to add multiple ISO images which you can then 'burn' to a single ISO image.

Looking at the reviews on the site, its been fairly successful.

---

Have a look at using YUMI (Your Universal Multiboot Integrator) http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/

This will allow you to put multiple distros onto one stick & then select which to boot from.

HTH

Comment: I would like an ISO, not a USB stick

Comment: Ah, apologies, my mistake.  I will have a look about and see what I can find for you.